# What should I do in this situation when something is out of scope?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct

The struct Song that was built in the first class, cannot be used in the second class. It keeps saying Song is out of scope. How should I change the code so that I can use Song in the second class?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!
    
    var songs = [Song]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureSongs()
        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    func configureSongs(){
        songs.append(Song(name: "Codiene Lemonade", albumName: "?", artistName: "Gunna ", imageName: "Cover3", trackName: "Song 3"))
        songs.append(Song(name: "Heavy Metal", albumName: "?", artistName: "Mike Dimes", imageName: "Cover2", trackName: "Song 2"))
        songs.append(Song(name: "No Role Modelz", albumName: "?", artistName: "J Cole", imageName: "Cover1", trackName: "Song 1"))
    }

    // table
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return songs.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let song = songs[indexPath.row]
        // configure
        cell.textLabel?.text = song.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = song.albumName
        cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: song.imageName)
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name:  "Helvetica-Bold", size: 18)
        cell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont(name:  "Helvetica", size: 17)
        
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
         return 100
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath , animated: true)
        
        //present the player
        let position = indexPath.row
        //songs
        guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "player") as? PlayerViewController else{
            return
        }
        vc.songs = Song
        vc.position =  position
        present(vc, animated: true)
    }
    
    struct Song{
        let name: String
        let albumName: String
        let artistName: String
        let imageName: String
        let trackName: String
    }

}



import UIKit


class PlayerViewController: UIViewController{
    

    
    public var position: Int = 0
    public var songs: [Song] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }
    
  
    
    
}
```

Comment: Create a new folder called Models. Then create a new file called Song, and put the Song struct in there. You need to place the Struct outside of the ViewController

Answer (score 3):

Cut the code:

```
struct Song{
    let name: String
    let albumName: String
    let artistName: String
    let imageName: String
    let trackName: String
}
```

and paste it outside the ViewController Class. A good practice is - Create a new swift file *Model.swift* and paste the struct in it. In this way the struct **Song** will be accessible from all the classes of the working project.